# python merge nested list that they are not same

Tags: python, list

I have lists of lists (nested):

```
l1 = [['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
l2 = m = ['8', '9']
```

I want to merge the two lists to have (the '8' and '9' append to each of the nested list).

```
l3 = [['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '8'],['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

Comment: Please provide your coding attempt, expand on exactly where the confusion lies, and provide the merging rules.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find *zip()* very useful for this:

```
l1 = [['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
l2 = ['8', '9']

for la, e in zip(l1, l2):
    la.append(e)

print(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
[['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '8'], ['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function ([python doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip))

> The zip() function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc.

Here is an example using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and typical for loop.

```
l = [[*i, j] for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]
print(l)

# or

l = []
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    i.append(j)
print(l)

# Output
[['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '8'],
 ['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

It works here because you have a list of lists and a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list comprehension:

```
l1 = [['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
l2 = ['8', '9']

l3 = [sublist + [elem] for sublist, elem in zip(l1, l2)]
```

The result would be:

```
[['3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '8'], ['1', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```